# Wrapping title text in Action Mode using a custom layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-appcompat, android-actionmode

I am trying make my contextual action bar, or CAB, behave in a [Material way](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-top.html#anatomy) such as wrapping title text when it is long. For the regular toolbar, I use appCompat.Toolbar, but for the CAB, I am using appCompat.ActionMode, which its attributes are mostly style-driven, but since the default TextView of the ActionMode does not seem to support line wrapping and instead ellipses, and there is no exposed method to set it to wrap, I am trying to find a solution to drive that behavior via style or programmatically setting it using the setCustomView method within overriding onCreateActionMode. If I don't find a way to do this, the CAB has potential to overlay weirdly on the toolbar that does wrap.

I have tried setting attributes in different parts of styling, creating a custom text view layout for the title of the CAB, setting it both in the style and programmatically using customView, but I can't seem to get anything to work.

I created a custom layout to be used either in my styles or my ContextualActionBar.

*context_action_mode_title_layout.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/action_mode_title"
            android:textColor="@color/warning"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:maxLines="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

In my *styles.xml*:

```
<resources>
<style name="CommonAppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Toolbar</item>
<item name="actionModeStyle">@style/CommonAppTheme.ContextActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/CommonAppTheme.ContextActionBar</item>
    </style>

<style name="Toolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/surface</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/on_background</item>
        <item name="android:titleTextColor">@color/on_background</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CommonAppTheme.ContextActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
        <item name="background">@color/on_surface</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/CommonAppTheme.ContextualTextStyle</item>
        <item name="tint">@color/surface</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
        <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/context_action_bar_title_layout</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CommonAppTheme.ContextualTextStyle">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/surface</item>
        <item name="android:displayOptions">showCustom</item>
        <item name="android:customNavigationLayout">@layout/context_action_bar_title_layout</item>
        <item name="android:maxLines">2</item>
        <item name="android:ellipsize">none</item>
    </style>
```

My *ContextualActionBar.kt* component:

```
class ContextualActionBar : ActionMode.Callback {

    var onActionItemClickListener: OnActionItemClickListener? = null

    private var mode: ActionMode? = null
    @MenuRes
    private var menuResId: Int = 0
    private var title: String? = null
    private var subtitle: String? = null

    override fun onCreateActionMode(mode: ActionMode?, menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        this.mode = mode
        mode?.menuInflater?.inflate(menuResId, menu)
        mode?.title = title
        mode?.subtitle = subtitle
        return true
    }

    fun startActionMode(view: View,
                        @MenuRes menuResId: Int,
                        title: String? = null,
                        subtitle: String? = null) {
        this.menuResId = menuResId
        this.title = title
        this.subtitle = subtitle
        view.startActionMode(this)
    }
```

I create an instance of this in my fragment's VM, then drive populating the title, subtitle, and menu res in the fragment class.

*These are the sections where I was not quite sure of the syntax of inflating my custom layout to be used when setting the values in the fragment on the CAB.*

I expected to be able to, in some way, say "use this custom layout" and set it with its layout behaviors, such as no ellipses and wrapping text to the amount of maxLines. Then when setting the title on a fragment-to-fragment basis, the CAB can handle long lines of text.